# Get CryptoAPI public key via PKCS#11

Tags: c++, cryptography, cryptoapi, pkcs#11

In my C++ program I created a public/private key pair using **CryptoAPI**.

```
CryptGenKey(eTokenProv,ENCRYPT_ALGORITHM,CRYPT_EXPORTABLE,&k1)
```

Keys are stored in a **eToken**.
Is it possible to get the public key using **PKCS#11**? The private key previously created is found after a search using the following search-template:

```
    CK_ATTRIBUTE private_search[] = {
       {CKA_PRIVATE, CK_TRUE, sizeof(CK_BBOOL)}
    };
```

If I set `CKA_PRIVATE` to CK_FALSE, I can't get the public key. I also tried with other attributes.
Is there a way to do it?

**EDIT**

As **owlstead** suggests, I tried to create a public key starting from the modulus and public exponent of a key created in a previous session (in CAPI or, just for this test, in PKCS11). I got the modulus and public exponent from a private key in these buffers:

```
CK_BYTE  modulus[128]; //if 1024bit
CK_BYTE  publicExponent[4]; //4 Byte, according to public key blob
```

But when I try to create a new public with key with the following instructions:

```
CK_ATTRIBUTE publicKeyTemplate[] = {
    {CKA_TOKEN, &yes, sizeof(true)},
    {CKA_WRAP, &yes, sizeof(true)},
    {CKA_ENCRYPT, &yes, sizeof(true)},
    {CKA_MODULUS_BITS, &modulusBits, sizeof(modulusBits)},
    {CKA_MODULUS, &modulus, sizeof(modulus)},
    {CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT, &publicExponent, sizeof(publicExponent)}

CK_MECHANISM mechanism = {CKM_RSA_PKCS_KEY_PAIR_GEN, NULL_PTR, 0 };
rv = (*functions->C_GenerateKeyPair) (session, &mechanism, publicKeyTemplate, 6, privateKeyTemplate, 6, &hPublicKey, &hPrivateKey);
```

I get the error "Invalid template". The probles is the modulus, because, without it, I can create a key pair. I use the function `C_GenerateKeyPair`, but I'm only interested in the public key. I omitted the private template.
What is the wrong here?

Comment: If you want to create a public key you should not use `C_GenerateKeyPair` basically, you should create a public key object using [`C_CreateObject`](https://www.cryptsoft.com/pkcs11doc/v220/pkcs11__all_8h.html#aC_CreateObject). Of course it fails if you try and create a **new** key pair with a pre-set modulus. Note that the **EDIT** contains a rather separate question from the original one. Oh, yeah, and I'm "owlstead" - I've stopped using my previous nick :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CKA_PRIVATE` does not indicate a private key at all.

> When the CKA_PRIVATE attribute is TRUE, a user may not access the object until the user 
>   has been authenticated to the token

Instead you should look for an attribute such as `CKA_CLASS` with a value `CKO_PUBLIC_KEY` or `CKO_PRIVATE_KEY`, possibly using other attributes to filter your results further.

If you cannot find any `CKO_PUBLIC_KEY` then I presume it was either not generated in the token (key was imported, check if `CKA_LOCAL` is set). Alternatively, it may have only been created as a session object. Finally it may have been removed.

Note that RSA private keys commonly do contain the public exponent, so you can still construct a public key from just the private key object (using the modulus and public exponent, of course).

Comment: ok, thank you for the answer!! I've done some tests and I found that: the private key (i.e. CKA_CLASS = CKO_PRIVATE_KEY) is not local - maybe because it was created via CAPI; no CKO_PUBLIC_KEY keys have been found. So, as you suggest, to re-build the public key we can get the CKA_MODULUS and CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT from the template of the private key. I'll try it!

Comment: If `CKA_LOCAL` is not set then you may want to take an extra look at the security of your setup. A private key is most safe if it is generated and left protected within the token (except possibly for an encrypted backup if your key management scheme does not allow for generating a new key).

Comment: If I create the private key via PKCS#11, CKA_LOCAL is set to true. Maybe, if it is not set, it depends on a CryptoAPI setting.. I'll check it. About the public key, I edit my question with other details.. any other suggestions? Thanks a lot

Comment: @andret8 Why do you need the public key to be in the PKCS#11 token? The public key is, well, public, so you don't need to protect it using  a cryptographic token. Just recreate the public key in software and use it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the reference symbol in CK_ATTRIBUTE when setting a pointer to a CK_BYTE array - in your case **modulus**.

```
CK_ATTRIBUTE publicKeyTemplate[] = {
    {CKA_TOKEN, &yes, sizeof(true)},
    {CKA_WRAP, &yes, sizeof(true)},
    {CKA_ENCRYPT, &yes, sizeof(true)},
    {CKA_MODULUS_BITS, &modulusBits, sizeof(modulusBits)},
    {CKA_MODULUS, modulus, sizeof(modulus)},
    {CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT, &publicExponent, sizeof(publicExponent)}
```

I haven't tested your code, but I am able to successfully obtain modulus of an CK_OBJECT_HANDLE (private key / public key) by setting following template and making a call to C_GetAttributeValue:

```
CK_BYTE         modulus[128];
CK_ATTRIBUTE    Modulus = { CKA_MODULUS, modulus, sizeof(modulus) };

if ((rv = (*p11FunctionList->C_GetAttributeValue)(hSession, hPrivKey /*hPubKey*/, &Modulus, 1)) == CKR_OK)
{
  // do something with obtained modulus
}
```

The generated private-public key pair was generated as follow:

```
CK_OBJECT_HANDLE    hPrivKey, hPubKey;
CK_BBOOL            bTrue   = TRUE;
CK_ULONG            mod_bits = 1024;
CK_MECHANISM        GenMechanism = { CKM_RSA_PKCS_KEY_PAIR_GEN, NULL_PTR, 0 };         

CK_ATTRIBUTE        GenPubTemplate[] = {
            { CKA_MODULUS_BITS, &mod_bits, sizeof(CK_ULONG) },
            { CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT, "\x01\x00\x01", 3 },
            { CKA_TOKEN, &bTrue, sizeof(CK_BBOOL) },
            { CKA_ID, (CK_CHAR_PTR)szKeyID, strlen(szKeyID) } }; // szKeyID is a const char *

        CK_ATTRIBUTE         GenPrivTemplate[] = {
            { CKA_TOKEN, &bTrue, sizeof(CK_BBOOL) },
            { CKA_PRIVATE, &bTrue, sizeof(CK_BBOOL) },
            { CKA_SENSITIVE, &bTrue, sizeof(CK_BBOOL) },
            { CKA_ID, (CK_CHAR_PTR)szKeyID, strlen(szKeyID) } }; // szKeyID is a const char *

// hSession is a CK_SESSION_HANDLE of an opened & logged in session 
if ((rv = (*p11FunctionList->C_GenerateKeyPair)(hSession, &GenMechanism, GenPubTemplate, 4, GenPrivTemplate, 4, &hPubKey, &hPrivKey)) == CKR_OK)
{
  // Now get the modulus of a the private / public key as described above 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this has already been answered for others who want to do this we have created a PKCS#11 based wrapper for CryptoAPI, you can find it here:

https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/pvpkcs11

With this you can access keys stored in CryptoAPI as well as certificates using the native PKCS#11 interfaces.